# Create a div dynamically and align it's bottom with the top of another component

Tags: jquery, css, validation, position, alignment

I am making a validation framework type of thing and when there are errors on a component I want to show a text box that displays the errors when the user mouses over. So I've created a method that does just that. The problem is I can't get it in the correct position. I want the bottom of my outer most div that I'm creating dynamically to be just on top of the element my mouse is over.

```
function onMouseOverHandler(event) {
        var validationContent = document.createElement("div");
        validationContent.setAttribute("class", "validationErrorContent");
        for(var i = 0; i < this.validationErrors.length; ++i) {
            if(i > 0) {
                $(validationContent).append("<br>");
            }
            $(validationContent).append(this.validationErrors[i].message);
        }

        var validationDiv = document.createElement("div");
        validationDiv.setAttribute("class", "validationErrorDiv");
        validationDiv.setAttribute("id", "validationErrorDiv");
        validationDiv.appendChild(validationContent);
        $(validationDiv).offset({ top: $(this).offset().top - $(this).height(), left: $(this).offset().left + $(this).width() - 5});
        document.body.appendChild(validationDiv);
    }
```

This doesn't work because the height of validationDiv is always 0 at this point.

In case anyone needs it, here is the associated CSS as well:

```
 .validationErrorDiv {position: absolute; display: block;}
.validationErrorContent {position: relative; color: white; background: red; width: 150px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Validation DIV will always have a single line of text. So you can add a `min-height` this way:

```
.validationErrorContent {
    position: relative;
    color: white; background: red;
    width: 150px; min-height: 1em;
}
```

Comment: It might not always have single line of text actually. There could be multiple validation errors at one time. I was able to fix the problem by just moving the offset line after the document.body.appendChild(validationDiv) line though.

Comment: No No. What I was saying was, at least it would have single line. So, this solution might work at times. Anyway, so you have fixed it right.